# Getting Call to a member function paginate() on array error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-paginate

I am getting Getting Call to a member function paginate() on array error in laravel with the following code

```
public static function search_query($query)
{
    $tokenizeitem = array();
    $tokenizeitem = queryarr($query);

    //$tokenizeitem = $this->bbbootstrap->tokenizeStringIntoFTSWords($item);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM snippets WHERE MATCH(snippets_name,seo_description) 
    AGAINST (' ";

    foreach ($tokenizeitem as $w) {
        $sql .= '+' . $w . '* ';
    }

    $sql .= "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

    $searchdata=DB::select( DB::raw($sql))->paginate(15);

    return $searchdata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory:

> Call to a member function paginate() on array error in laravel

your following code:

```
DB::select( DB::raw($sql))->paginate(15);
```

return an array and you can't call `paginate()` on array. So instead of this use:

```
DB::table("your query")->paginate();
```

[Laravel Raw Query Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: can i pass $sql inside table like DB::table($sql)->paginate();

Comment: Then i am not able to understand how to rectify!

Comment: Search, you will get something

Comment: I did it like this and getting results but pagination not working now $searchdata = DB::table('snippets')
                      ->selectRaw("*")
                      ->whereRaw($sql)
                      ->paginate(20);

Comment: Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090392/how-to-use-pagination-with-laravel-dbselect-query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210645/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-upasana-chauhan).