# Laravel Lighthouse paginate field result

Tags: laravel, graphql, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse

I have defined a query in lighthouse:

```
extend type Query {
    products(input: ListInput @spread): [Product]
        @field(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\ProductComplex@index")
}
```

but the result of `products` is not paginated. I can not use both `@field` and `@paginate` at the same time because there should be only one resolver. How can I paginate an eloquent query with custom resolver?

I've searched and found that I `builder` could be used but I don't want to use query builders when I have defined the appropriate model.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? If you did, do you mind answering the question yourself? I am struggling with the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find the solution:

```
extend type Query {
    products(captionId: ID, subFieldId: ID, q: String): [Product]
    @paginate(type: "paginator" defaultCount: 10 maxCount: 100
        builder: "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\ProductComplex@index")
}
```

Just nedded to use `builder` inside `paginate` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Just add pagination to your query `$posts = DB::table('posts')->paginate(12);`

Also, here you will found several solutions to this problem:
[How to use pagination with laravel DB::select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090392/how-to-use-pagination-with-laravel-dbselect-query)

Cheer.