# Showing Errors while executing Laravel Code for Pagination : db:select().paginate(10)

Tags: php, laravel

I need help for Laravel 8

Here is my code :

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE LEFT JOIN DESIGNATION ON EMPLOYEE.DGNO = DESIGNATION.DGNO WHERE DESGINATION.NAME='IT' ORDER BY EMPLOYEE.NAME")->paginate(10);

return view('Employee.Index', $data);
```

Comment: First of all, you have a syntax error - in PHP `.` is not used to access object properties/methods, we use `->`. Also, It's not that simple to create pagination with `DB::select`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pagination with laravel DB::select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090392/how-to-use-pagination-with-laravel-dbselect-query)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
DB::table('employee')
->leftJoin('designation', 'employee.dgno', '=', 'designation.dgno')
->where('designation.name', '=', "IT")
->orderBy('employee.name', 'asc')
->paginate(10);
```

Comment: thanks! but I am trying to build query builder so I need this above :select

Comment: why you need to use query builder. as your solution is available